# Could not find element /manifest/application in play-services\4.0.30\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I am updating project in AndroidStudio,  used **target API 20 instead of 19**. During this process I encounter this error:

> [PathToMyProject]\myproject\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.0.30\AndroidManifest.xml:
>   Error:(1) Could not find element /manifest/application. //showing
>   several times

This is the file AndroidManifest.xml where is the error:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.google.android.gms"
        android:versionCode="4030530"
        android:versionName="4.0.30 (889083-30)" >
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    </manifest>
```

When I add `<application/>` tag and run Make or Rebuild, the manifest is for an unknown reason refreshed and does not contain added `<application>` tag and the error shows again...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You need to change the build.gradle to get the gms version for wearables.

So, add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'` to dependencies, and it should work.